# PHP Arrays gatther arrays from previous post

Tags: php, arrays

Using WP I'm building the breakdown of a score. Each breakdown is a custom select field with values from 1 to 10. The final result i'm trying to achieve is to show the total score inside the WP loop, by calculating the sum of all breakdown scores and dividing it by the number of added breakdown scores.

The problem is that each post i add with the total score it taking the array from a previous posts also. For example:

**Post 1**

```
array(6) { [0]=> array(0) { } [1]=> string(1) "7" [2]=> string(2) "10" [3]=> string(1) "9" [4]=> string(2) "10" [5]=> string(1) "1" }
```

**Post 2**

```
array(9) { [0]=> array(0) { } [1]=> string(1) "7" [2]=> string(2) "10" [3]=> string(1) "9" [4]=> string(2) "10" [5]=> string(1) "1" [6]=> array(0) { } [7]=> string(1) "1" [8]=> string(1) "3" }
```

**Post 3**

```
array(13) { [0]=> array(0) { } [1]=> string(1) "7" [2]=> string(2) "10" [3]=> string(1) "9" [4]=> string(2) "10" [5]=> string(1) "1" [6]=> array(0) { } [7]=> string(1) "1" [8]=> string(1) "3" [9]=> array(0) { } [10]=> string(1) "9" [11]=> string(2) "10" [12]=> string(1) "3" }
```

As you can see Post 2 got it's own array and the array from Post 1, Post 3 got it's own array and arrays from Post 1 and Post 2.

This is the code i'm using inside the WP while loop

```
<?php
$score_rows = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'review_score', true);
$score[] = array();

foreach( $score_rows as $row ):
    $score[] = $row['score_number'];
endforeach;

$score_items = count( $score ); 
$score_divide = $score_items;
$score_sum = array_sum( $score );
$score_total = $score_sum / $score_divide;
?>
```

This code works great in single.php where i have only one post, but what to do where i have more then one? How to prevent from posts to combine arrays like this?

**UPDATE**
I have found that all the values are strings, maybe this is what causing it act like this. Is it possible to convert the values to integers?

Comment: have you tried array_merge?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I don't want to merge the arrays i want each post to have it's own array as it should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
$score[] = array();
```

to

```
$score = array();
```

Comment: Yes, that was the problem, i have found it and just wanted to write the solution here. Thank you, RST, for your response.